# Guessing game - stuck in loop.

Tags: c, if-statement

I am working on a guessing game program. The main function asks the user to guess a number and if that number does not equal the correct guess, it is sent to a different function that tells the user if that number is too high or too low. The second function then asks the user for another guess and that guess is sent back to the first function.

My code gets trapped in the second function and does not appear to exit it. I'm not sure what to change.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int guess(int num);

int main(void)
{
    int units;  

    printf("How many legs on a wonderwump??\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &units);
    while (units != 56)
    {
        guess(units);
    }
    printf("Great guess!\n");
    return 0;
}

int guess(int num)
{

    if (num > 56)
    {
        printf("Too high of a guess! Try again!");
    }
    else // (num < 56)
    {
        printf("Too low of a guess! Try again!");
    }

return scanf_s("%d", &num);

}
```

Comment: `units=guess(units) ;`

Comment: the `guess()` function is returning etiher 0 or ` or EOF, not the actual guess value.  This is because this line: `return scanf("%d", &num);` is returning the status from the call to `scanf()` and not the contents of `num`  And the caller of the function is not even checking the returned value.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this code block: `while (units != 56)
    {
        guess(units);
    }` is never updating the variable 'units' in the main() function, so this loop will run forever.

Comment: suggest reading the man page for `scanf_s()`  and for portability suggest calling `scanf()` instead.   if running under windows, this may require the line: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the beginning of your program

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `units` value after each time you call the second function, because right now it is never being changed.

So change

```
while (units != 56) {
  guess(units);
}
```

to

```
while (units != 56) {
  units = guess(units);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I still get stuck in either the if or else in the second function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Replace the `guess` function with:

```
int guess(int num)
{

    if (num > 56)
    {
        printf("Too high of a guess! Try again!");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (num < 56)
    {
        printf("Too low of a guess! Try again!");
        return 1;
    } else 
        return 0;
}
```

and

```
while (units != 56)
{
    guess(units);
}
```

should be

```
while (1)
{
    if(guess(units) == 0)
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `guess(units)` you are passing variable by value (value is copied), you can send it by reference with `guess(&units)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void guess(int* num);

int main(void)
{
    int units;  

    printf("How many legs on a wonderwump??\n");
    scanf("%d", &units);
    while (units != 56)
    {
        guess(&units);
    }
    printf("Great guess!\n");
    return 0;
}

void guess(int* num)
{
    if (*num > 56)
        printf("Too high of a guess! Try again!\n");
    else // (num < 56)
        printf("Too low of a guess! Try again!\n");
    scanf("%d", num);
}
```